# .ui-dialog button.ui-button.ui-state-hover .ui-button-text{color:black} to jquery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, dialog

I was trying  all day long without success to convert `CSS` to `jQuery`.

CSS code :

```css
.ui-dialog button.ui-button.ui-state-hover .ui-button-text{color:black}
```

I thought it could be something like this.

jQuery :

```js
$(".ui-dialog > button.ui-button.ui-state-hover > .ui-button-text").css('color','black');
```

But it is not working. The goal would be to change the button text color of `jquery-ui dialog`, when hovering the button.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you very much in advance!
Bye

Comment: Indent your code with 4 spaces

Comment: Looking at the jqueryui dialog demo, their buttons have a little more nesting than that, down into a `ui-buttonset`, then a `ui-widget`, using the browser inspect checking the styles. Might have to do the same to see if more classes may be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo based on the [jQuery](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation) demo:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height: "auto",
    width: 400,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      "Delete all items": function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      },
      Cancel: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }
  });

  $(".ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonset button").hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight");
  }, function() {
    $(this).removeClass("ui-state-highlight");
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Empty the recycle bin?">
  <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:12px 12px 20px 0;"></span>These items will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?</p>
</div>

<p>Sed vel diam id libero <a href="http://example.com">rutrum convallis</a>. Donec aliquet leo vel magna. Phasellus rhoncus faucibus ante. Etiam bibendum, enim faucibus aliquet rhoncus, arcu felis ultricies neque, sit amet auctor elit eros a lectus.</p>
```

> **Theming**

> The dialog widget uses the jQuery UI CSS framework to style its look and feel. If dialog specific styling is needed, the following CSS class names can be used for overrides or as keys for the classes option:

> `ui-dialog`: The outer container of the dialog.

> `ui-dialog-buttonset`: The container around the buttons themselves.

The Example above uses `hover()` to add and remove a class that can be used to style the button(s) inside the dialog box. See more: https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/